# What is wrong with wordpress code for displaying random popular posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
$args_popular = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'meta_key'='wpb_post_views_count',              
'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
'posts_per_page' => $entries_display,
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'   ,
'order' => 'rand()',
array(
    'key'     => 'wpb_post_views_count',
    'value'   => '1000',
    'compare' => '>=',
    ),                              
);  
?>
```

I need to display popular posts whose views >1000 and the posts need to be random. This is the code I have written.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of issues here

- `order` value is invalid, valid values are `ASC` and `DESC`
- To order random, `orderby` needs to be set to `rand`
- You do not need to set the `meta_key` as you are ordering randomly
- You `meta_query` is incomplete. Your array should be wrappped in another array, and parameter should be `meta_query`

This should work

```
$args_popular = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => $entries_display,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'wpb_post_views_count',
            'value'   => '1000',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'decimal',
        ),
    ),                              
);
```

Comment: Not working is not a valid problem description. Please explain what the **exact** problem is

Comment: Everytime the page is refreshed the same posts are visible. There is no change in visible posts or order.

Comment: Have you disabled cache plugins and cleared all caches.

Comment: Yes. i have cleared all caches. Shouldn't it be meta_key instead of key ?

Comment: No, inside a meta_query there is no `meta_` prefix. I can't really see any issue. Do the correct posts display, do you only get posts with >1000 views

Comment: No there are some posts with views <1000

Comment: Then, for some reason, your meta_query is failing. Do you have any other custom queries on the same page or any filters that might influence this

Comment: It is taking 1000 as character. Rest everything is working fine

Comment: edit
add type='decimal'
and everything will work fine